Is there a way to find out the path from getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir of another app?
Android API provides getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir to find out an app's /data/app lib path, as explained in previous questions How to get the path to the lib folder for an installed package or Get Android application lib directory, for example. On Android 14, for an app com.some.app, it will looks something like this:
/data/app/~~7BZ-8zEDb3gzGGndbbDhg9==/com.some.app-GQePpzWb2GhdgZ8qftAnrH==/lib

However, obviously that command only works being called by the app itself, which the lib path belongs to. I want to find out the path for another app, though. It is possible via ADB and USB debugging with:
adb shell dumpsys package com.some.app | grep legacyNativeLibraryDir

How can I find out the path from my phone without having to use USB debugging?

Even if you had that path, you don't have any access to anything in that path. What exactly are you trying to do?

What do you want to achieve? If you just want to get the .so library files you can get the APK file and extract the .so files yourself.

Libraries are binaries, but usually they can not be executed, only loaded into an existing process (via System.loadlibrary / dlopen). And even if you have read access to already unpacked .so files you may not have execute permission. Also recent apps do no longer unpack .so files when installed, so for those apps you have to extract them from APK file anyway.

@Robert Thanks for the reply! :) You have valid concerns, however the app in question has set android:extractNativeLibs=true so the .so files will get extracted and I already know that they're executables. Also the app folder in /data/app is system-owned and read-execute for everyone. Maybe you're thinking of the app folder in /data/user/0 (i.e. /data/data) which is indeed prohibiting execution, due to being app-owned and read-write for each app individually. It's Android's W^X policy.

@ianhanniballake See my comment above. Shared native libraries in /data/app are read-execute for all apps. I have already tested that execution from a terminal app works - on Android 14, too. The only thing that I had to find out for it to work was the path and I want to be able to find that out from the phone, instead of having to manually find out the path through USB debugging. Any ideas?
